# Get the first item in a sequence that matches a condition

Tags: python, comparative-review

I've been trying to figure out what's the best, most Pythonic way to get the first element of a sequence that matches a condition. Here are three options:

1. I don't like that I've written `caller[0].f_locals.get("runner")` twice, but it feels most Pythonic otherwise.

   ```py
   runner = next(
       caller[0].f_locals.get("runner")
       for caller in inspect.stack()
       if isinstance(caller[0].f_locals.get("runner"), AbstractRunner)
   )
   ```
2. Is it weird to rely on an assignment during the loop?

   ```py
   for caller in inspect.stack():
       runner = caller[0].f_locals.get("runner")
       if isinstance(runner, AbstractRunner):
           break
   ```
3. The second line is Pythonic and all, but the first line is only there to set up a generator where you no longer have to compute the expression (only apply the conditional in the second line).

   ```py
   generator = (caller[0].f_locals.get("runner") for caller in inspect.stack())
   runner = next(x for x in generator if isinstance(x, AbstractRunner))
   ```

There's no performance difference at all from my tests.

Comment: You don't have to do the assignment twice if you nest, `runner = next(runner for runner in (caller[0].f_locals.get("runner") for caller in inspect.stack()) if isinstance(runner, AbstractRunner))`. This is basically a hybrid of your first and third options. I'd consider it fairly pythonic if written out in multiple lines in a readable way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a use case for the walrus operator `:=`, which was [introduced in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions). It allows you to write 1) without repeating yourself:

```
runner = next(
    r
    for caller in inspect.stack()
    if isinstance(r := caller[0].f_locals.get("runner"), AbstractRunner)
)
```

Whether or not you find this more readable or if this is too much nestedness in the `if` part is up to personal taste.

Comment: This is great! I unfortunately can't use this, as my code is for a library plugin that needs to support Python 3.6-3.8, but accepting as this answers my question as to how to most elegantly avoid duplication.

Comment: Actually there's a more specific reason not to do this than just thinking `:=` smells bad. The assignment of `r` is happening in the surrounding scope (so in the same scope as `runner`). In cases where you really want a walrus operator, this is probably the behavior you'd need, but in this situation you're cluttering the namespace, _conceivably_ introducing bugs. A minimal demonstration that works in 3.8.6: `[*[y for x in [1] if (y:=x) < 5], y]`

Comment: The walrus operator can be really useful. But in this case, it really has a weird flow. It doesn't feel Pythonic at all to use a variable before it is (apparently) defined.

Comment: @EricDuminil Isn't that because of the generator expression rather than because of the walrus?

Comment: @superbrain: It's the mix of both which I find not readable. `x for x in some_list if foo(x)` can be read almost as an English instance. It's hard to read the above code without "by the way" or "I forgot to mention what `r` is". OP's 3rd proposal is very readable and the closest to the Zen of Python. We can use the walrus operator here but I don't think we should. My $0.02.

Comment: @EricDuminil For what it's worth, I kind of agree. I always want to write the SyntaxError `[y := f(x) for x in foo if g(y)]` instead of the "correct" one `[y for x in foo if g(y := f(x))]`.

Comment: @Graipher: Thanks for the comment. I still think that two lines with two comprehensions would be more readable. Walrus operator can be really useful for `while` or for regex matches but not in this case IMHO. I always want to write `[y for y in x for x in some_list]` instead of the correct `[y for x in some_list for y in x]`.

Answer (score 13):

I have to be honest, I actually prefer option `3`, and it's what I've used previously. It gives a clear separation of steps: "Produce the data, then filter it".

For a simpler case, I might go with @Graipher's suggestion. I have nothing against `:=`; I use it regularly. That last line of his in particular though is getting a bit noisy, and takes some processing to see what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

You could also avoid your duplication with the single-value list idiom:

```
runner = next(
    runner
    for caller in inspect.stack()
    for runner in [caller[0].f_locals.get("runner")]
    if isinstance(runner, AbstractRunner)
)
```

Separates getting the runner from checking its type, works in older Python's as well, doesn't leak like the walrus does, and since 3.9, it's ["as fast as a simple assignment"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations).

Comment: Interesting. It's easier to read than the `:=` answer, and it has a better flow. I personally still find it less readable than OP's 3rd version, though.

Answer (score 6):

**I would vote against the walrus operator here; it's a clear case of doing two things at once.**

Your original (#1) is probably good. I like that you're directly assigning the final value to its variable without preamble. If the repetition is really bugging you (or if the `get` function is expensive), then you could just nest generators

```py
runner = next(
    r
    for r in (caller[0].f_locals.get("runner")
              for caller in inspect.stack())
    if isinstance(r, AbstractRunner)
)
```

or abandon comprehension-syntax

```py
runner = next(filter(lambda r: isinstance(r, AbstractRunner),
                     map(lambda c: c[0].f_locals.get("runner"),
                         inspect.stack())))
```

Some people don't like lambdas; they're one of python's weak points. Unfortunately we hit several other weak points if we try to get rid of them: `functools.partial` won't work on `isinstance` (it takes positional args only, and we want to lock the second arg), and there's no built-in composition operator which is what we'd need for the `map`.

Really any of the repetitious comprehension, the nested comprehension, or the filter-&-map, or some hybrid, would be fine.